# How to pass multiple parameters in a function in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to run a Powershell script for a runbook in an automation account in Azure. I am using a function to pass multiple parameters. The runbook is for restoring disks of VM. However from the code structure that I am using it doesn't seem like I can pass in more than 1 Resource Name. How do I restructure this code or how do I frame my function or anyone of the lines in the script in order to pass more than one Resource Name (VM names in this case) ?

Currently I can pass only one Resource Name in the function but I need to pass two VM names.

```
function DiskRestore($ResourceName, $storageAccount)
{

 try
 {
  .....
  .....
  .....
       $resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName"samplerg" -ResourceName  $ResourceName

  .....
  .....
  .....
       $restorejob = Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -RecoveryPoint $rp[0] -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountResourceGroupName "samplerg"

  .....
  .....
  .....
  }
  }

  DiskRestore -ResourceName "samplevm01" -storageAccount "samplesa01"
```

So in the above function how can I pass one more VM name apart from samplevm01. How can I pass samplevm02 ? The storage account remains the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reparse `$ResourceName` inside the function if it's an array, run a foreach cycle on the data in there and have fun.

Comment: If the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [Vesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627055/vesper), change the parameter definition to receive a string array and loop through that array with `foreach{..}`.
Personally I would extend this a little by putting the parameters in a `Param()` block to create an 'advanced function'. By doing so, the function automatically gains extra common PowerShell parameters like `ErrorAction`, `Verbose` etc.
Also, I would rename the function so it complies with the `Verb-Noun` naming convention for PowerShell functions.

Something like this:

```
function Restore-Disk {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ResourceName,

        [string]$ResourceGroupName = 'samplerg',  # add a default name for this parameter

        [string]$StorageAccount = 'samplesa01',   # add a default name for this parameter

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $RecoveryPoint
    )
    foreach ($resource in $ResourceName) {
        try {
            #  .....
            # This will only print to the console is the -Verbose parameter is used on the function
            Write-Verbose "Retrieve resource '$resource' in group '$ResourceGroupName'"
            $resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName  $resource
            #  .....
            Write-Verbose "Restoring data and configuration for group '$ResourceGroupName'"
            $restorejob = Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -RecoveryPoint $RecoveryPoint -StorageAccountName $StorageAccount -StorageAccountResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
            #  .....
        }
        catch {}
    }
}

# Because the parameters ResourceGroupName and StorageAccount have default values, you do not have to specify them
# in the call to the function unless the are different than the default values.
Restore-Disk -ResourceName "samplevm01","samplevm02" -RecoveryPoint $rp[0] -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the powershell in `powershell runbook`, you can just pass the vm names in a string type and separated by a comma, like "vm1,vm2,vm3". Then in your runbook code, split the string to array, then in the foreach loop, operates with each vm.

A simple test in powershell runbook:

```
param([string]$ResourceName,[string]$StorageAccount)

#parse the string to an array
$vms = $ResourceName.split(',')

#implement your logic here
foreach($r in $vms)
{   
   #output the vm name
   $r
}

#output the storage account
$StorageAccount
```

Pass the parameters and run:

[image]

For your code, you can follow the above steps, your code in runbook should look like below:

```
param([string]$ResourceName,[string]$StorageAccount)

$vms = $ResourceName.split(',')

foreach ($resource in $vms) {
        try {
            #.....
            $resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "samplerg" -ResourceName  $resource

            $restorejob = Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -RecoveryPoint $rp[0] -StorageAccountName $StorageAccount -StorageAccountResourceGroupName "samplerg"

           #....
        }
        catch {}
    }
```